# n-loop is a sequence of n points

Tags: number-theory

Given two points $P$ and $Q$ with both integer coordinates (lattice points), we say that $P$see the point $Q$ if the segment $PQ$ contains no other lattice points. An n-loop is a sequence of n points $P_1, P_2, ..., P_n$, each of which is a lattice point, such that the following conditions are met:

a) $P_i$ sees $P_i+1$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n-1$ and $P_n$ sees $P_1$;

b) No $P_i$ sees any other Pj , except those mentioned in item a);

c) There are no three collinear points.
Determine if there is a 100-loop.

I was trying to force an arithmetic progression between the coordinates of three points to try to arrive at an absurdity, but I didn't get anything useful.

Comment: Is $P_i$ represented by two coordinates $(x,y)$? if so, what does $P_i+1$ mean? If not, how is $P_i$ represented?